# Jenkins deleting latest build when SCM polling is configured

Tags: jenkins

I have a maven jenkins job which builds to a directory called 'build.x86_64'. All of the artifacts are built to this directory. For some reason if I enable SCM polling, this directory gets deleted after the build completes. I can't see anything in the console output which says it is deleting the target.

Jenkins does however keep the build artifacts in it's own configured directory

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/[my job]/builds
```

I have a downstream job which needs the artifacts but they keep getting deleting.

If I turn off SCM polling and use the 'Build Now' option in the GUI, it doesn't delete the build directory. I can' see anything in the configuration which could cause this. The jenkins job is cloned from one with the same configuration. The problem does not occur in the job I cloned from.

Comment: What kind of SCM are you using?  Do you use `Archive the artifacts` to save them, but they get deleted? Or do you intend to copy them from the workspace of your job to another workspace? If they vanish from your workspace, can you triple check that your SCM settings dont involve something that resets or deletes your workspace, like i.e. a subversion revert + update policy?

Comment: I am using git - I have made no changes to the git settings. I am using `Archive the artifacts`, which archives to `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs`. Even if I don't use the archive build step, it shouldn't delete the build.

Comment: Agreed this sounds odd, usually the workspace stays. The artifacts you archived, do those vanish too?

Comment: You have provided an interesting case, but no resources for anyone to help you debug. I think you're more likely to get help by posting a bug to the [Jenkins Jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) with your Jenkins and plugin versions, job configuration, the job output and excerpts from the Jenkins log.

Comment: It is the SCM polling which is deleting the directory. This happens regardless of whether there are builds running or not. I have checked crontabs on the slave, and there are none configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the misconfiguration of the Source Code Management section of the Jenkins config. Under the `Additional Behaviours` section I had added, `Clean before checkout`. It should have been set to `Clean after checkout`.